# Stored Procedure using a table valued function and cursor. Getting cursor doesn't exist error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I getting the following error when running a stored procedure. The stored procedure calls a function that declares a cursor for a table using a function that returns a table value function. Please note I didn't include the declaration section of the code

```
declare cust_trn cursor local for SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Q03_Create_Customer_Trn](@COUNTERPARTY)

IF CURSOR_STATUS('local','cust_trn') <>-1 
BEGIN
    OPEN cust_trn
END

FETCH NEXT FROM cust_trn  INTO @trn,@cust_name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
  BEGIN    
      IF (@LIST1 IS NULL) BEGIN
          SET @LIST1= @cust_name;
      END
      ELSE BEGIN
          SET @LIST1=ISNULL(@LIST1, '') + ';' + ISNULL(@cust_name, '');
      END 
   FETCH NEXT FROM cust_trn INTO @trn,@cust_name; END   END ELSE BEGIN  SET @LIST1 = 'N/A'; END CLOSE cust_trn ; DEALLOCATE  cust_trn; RETURN ISNULL(@LIST1,'N/A'); END; ISNULL(@LIST1,'N/A'); END;
```

The error is **A cursor with the name 'cursor_name' does not exist** the function is begin called as **dbo.Q03_get_list_of_counterparties(COUNTERPARTY, 'Y') CParties** in the stored procedure.

Comment: Why not just `OPEN cust_trn` without the check. You know it exists because you've declared it one line before.

Comment: Why are you using a cursor here in the first place? Doing this row by agonizing row is not how you want to handle data. You can generate a delimited list a LOT simpler and faster than using a cursor.

Comment: you should write cursors in sql-server as a LAST RESORT.  they perform horribly.  Sql-Server is best written as set-based code.  you should write a new question and ask for help on "before" and "what I need after" without mentioning a cursor.  Please stop writing cursor code in sql-server.

Comment: can you please share code for 'Q03_Create_Customer_Trn'?

Comment: I returning a list of counterparties relating to a customer

Answer (score 1):

You entire cursor logic could be rewritten to something along these lines.

```
declare @List varchar(500) = '' --use whatever size is relevant.

select @List = @List + cust_name + ';'
from [dbo].[Q03_Create_Customer_Trn](@COUNTERPARTY)

select @List = left(@List, len(@List) - 1) --removes the last comma
```

Another option would be to use STUFF and FOR XML. There are hundreds and hundreds of examples of this all over the internet.

Comment: Upvote for this...(or anything) that points away from RBAR (row by agonizing row) cursors.